# multi stage opamp exercise

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Hello,
I'm trying to solve this exercise. I have to find R1,R2,R3 given that Vout=4v. I annotated my solution so far with red, but I can't go any further, what am I missing? I'm confused by the load resistor R3. Should it be placed in parallel with R2, or with the 50KΩ resistor. If neither, then I1=I2 and R1=8*R2, but I cant find any more information to continue.

Comment: If they are ideal op-amps then R3 has zero effect on the circuit. It might be a trick question or it might be a question set by someone who has made a mistake.

Comment: Great, thank you. Acording to a simulation I made, varying R3 indeed has not effect on the circuit as long as R1=8*R2.
p.s. the opamps are ideal

Comment: Lol, mean teacher

Comment: If it was CMOS and you needed rail to rail then the load regulation error or current limits might be an issue. But not here.  This is purely a simple academic exercise and not relevant to good design using 3 Op Amps to divide by 2.